# How to find the the canonical equation of the projection of the line?

Tags: analytic-geometry

How to find the the canonical equation of the projection of the line
$$\frac{1}{3} \left(x - 4\right) = -\frac{1}{2} \left(y + 1\right) = \frac{z}{4}$$

on the plane 
$$x-3y-z+8=0.$$

Comment: A line is defined by two points. Find two points on the line’s projection.

Comment: @amd,can you show me how ?

Comment: Another possibility is to convert the line into parametric form, project that onto the plane, then convert back. The other method is probably simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the hint given by [**amd**](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/265466/amd) in the comment, two points on the line are given by

- $P=(4,-1,0)$
- $Q=(7,-3,4)$

to find the projections of the points onto the plane we can consider the lines through the two points and orthogonal to the plane (i.e. direction vector = normal vector for the plane)

- $P(t)=(4,-1,0)+t(1,-3,-1)$
- $Q(t)=(7,-3,4)+t(1,-3,-1)$

and then find by the intersections the projection $P_0$ and $Q_0$ onto the plane.

Comment: and how does the ending of this solution looks like ?

Comment: @Elvin Did you succed in finding the projection?

Comment: ,yes, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Elvin ah ok well done! sorry but I lost you previuos comment! Bye